# How do I use the JQuery toggle ability to toggle the visibility of a group of rects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this function to show and hide objects. I think the reason why this isn't working is because I am not selecting the object correctly.

```
function generalHideOrShow(element)
    {
        if (element instanceof Element)
        {
            //single element passed
            element = [element]; //mimic node list
        }
        if(element.length && element.length > 0 && element[0] instanceof Element)
        {
            //node list
            for (var i = 0; i < element.length; ++i)
            {

                if (element[i].getAttribute("data-hidden") == "true" )
                {
                    $(element[i]).removeClass("hidden");
                    element[i].setAttribute("data-hidden", false);
                }
                else
                {
                    element[i].setAttribute("data-hidden", true);
                    $(element[i]).addClass("hidden");
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }

d3.selectAll("#button1").on("click", function(){

     generalHideOrShow($("#buttonsRight")); //selection
});

var buttons = d3.select("#svg").append("g").attr("id", "buttons");
var buttonsRightTop = buttons.append("g").attr("id", "buttonsRightTop");
var buttonsRight = buttonsRightTop.append("g").attr("id", "buttonsRight");
```

I wish to select 'buttonsRight' as above.

When I change it to select all 'div' tags to test it, it works.

generalHideOrShow($("div")); //selection

I have tried different ways of selecting it such as :

```
generalHideOrShow($(buttonsRight)); //selection
generalHideOrShow($(".buttonsRight")); //selection
generalHideOrShow($("g#buttonsRight")); //selection
```

None are working. How do I select this right side buttons ?

Comment: You are passing a jQuery object to the function `generalHideOrShow` which is not an instance of `Element`, try `generalHideOrShow($(".buttonsRight").get());`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, I think you can write it as

```
function generalHideOrShow(element) {
    var $elem = $(element);
    if ($elem.length) {
        var $hid = $elem.filter('[data-hidden="true"]').removeClass('hidden').attr("data-hidden", false);
        $elem.not($hid).addClass('hidden').attr("data-hidden", true);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: knew I wasn't selecting it properly. However when I log the element to console, i get this output : "[clone: function]" and nothing gets hidden ?

Comment: when i change it to "#buttonsRight" i get this output : "[g#buttonsRight, clone: function]" and still nothing changes

Comment: and the new function you gave me gives me this error : "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" :(

Comment: @rekoDolph there was an error, which is fixed now.. `[data-hidden=="true"]` is wrong... what is the jQuery version used

Comment: @rekoDolph my initial assumption was wrong, your code also is working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vovtt9z9/2/

Comment: its not working with the groups i created though. Example: "var buttonsRight = buttonsRightTop.append("g").attr("id", "buttonsRight");"

Comment: thanks for your help, managed to create my own way of doing it, think its much simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to do it:

Call the generalHideOrShow Function with the onClick:

```
d3.select("thisButton").on("click", function(){
generalHideOrShow("#buttonsRight");
}
```

set the class to `visible` first so you can check the class later:

```
buttonsRight.classed("visible", true);
```

Then do if statements to check if the class is `hidden` or `visible`

```
function generalHideOrShow(element) {
    console.log(element[0].getAttribute('class'));
    if(element[0].getAttribute('class') === "visible"){
        element[0].setAttribute('class', "hidden");
    } else{
        element[0].setAttribute('class', "visible");        
    }
```